# sound should start again when over

Tags: objective-c, ios4, audio, avaudioplayer, repeat

i've got a sound which is started when the app starts, it's 30 seconds long. how can I repeat the song when it's over no matter in which viewcontroller i am?

my code:

```
-(void)playBgMusic {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bgmusic" ofType:@"aif"];
theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio play];    }


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

if(self)
{
    [self playBgMusic];
}

return self; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1
```

Look at [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW12) for more info.

The owner of the audioPlayer instance should be the appDelegate then to let it play wherever the user is in the app.

Comment: thank you, an error comes up when i put it in the appdelegate but it works in my viewcontroller too